# Highchart point is not right in its line

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

I'm using Highchart (Highstock type) for my statistic. But got a  slight problem. 
I'm using angular version of [highchart](https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng).

See below screenshot:

[image: Problem]

As you can see the point is not in correct line with 25 December. 
I've tried to remove all my style but still like that.

Here is my data to use for highcharts:

And here is my setting:

```
var arr = [[1450976400000, 265567],[1451062800000,263272],[1451149200000,268065],[1451235600000,197184]];
$scope.chartConfig = {
    useHighStocks: true,
    options: {
        title: {
            text: 'Hello'
        },
        chart: {
            type: 'StockChart',
            zoomType: 'x',
            alignTicks: true
        },
        navigator: {enabled: false},
        scrollbar: {enabled: false},
        legend: {enabled: true},
        tooltip: {
            dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                millisecond: "%A, %b %e",
                second: "%A, %b %e",
                minute: "%A, %b %e",
                hour: "%A, %b %e",
                day: "%A, %b %e, %Y",
                week: "Week from %A, %b %e, %Y",
                month: "%B %Y",
                year: "%Y"
            }
        }
    },
    series: []

};

$scope.chartConfig.series.push(
    {
        name: key,
        gapSize: 5,
        type: 'area',
        data: arr,
        animation: true,
        marker: {
            enabled: true,
            radius: 3
        },
        shape: 'square',
        shadow: true
    }
);
```

Any solution?

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z1rar1sq/4/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Highcharts uses UTC. So `1450976400000` is `Thu Dec 24 2015 17:00:00`.

### Solution 1

Use UTC.

```
var offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset(); // PST: offset = 1020
value = 1450976400000 - offset * 60e3; //1450915200000
```

with [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

```
moment.utc('2015-12-24').valueOf(); //1450915200000
moment.utc([2015, 12, 24]).valueOf(); //1450915200000
```

### Solution 2

Use [`global.timezoneOffset`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#global.timezoneOffset)

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
   global: {
    timezoneOffset: 17 * 60
  }
});
```

Comment: I use your first solution with moment. and it works great. Tried second one but got `undefined 'info'`.

Comment: Oh, Really? I've updated your jsfiddle in the second solution. Hope that helps. https://jsfiddle.net/z1rar1sq/5/

Comment: ah now it make sense. I put the options at wrong place. Thanks!